# Node.js - sharing sockets among modules with require

Tags: node.js, loops, dependencies, socket.io, require

I'm using socket.io. In `app.js` I set up it and whenever a connection is established, I add the new socket to `sockets` array. I want to share `sockets` among modules such as **routes** by `require()`. However, `app.js` also requires the **routes**, so it forms a require loop. Here's the code.

```
// app.js
var route = require('routes/route')
    , sockets = [];

exports.sockets = sockets;

// route.js
var sockets = require('../app').sockets;  // undefined
```

How can I resolve the loop? Or are there other approaches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do all your socket.IO work inside the route file

```
var route = require('routes/route').init(io)
```

with in routes.js

```
var io;
exports.init = function(io) {
  io = io    
}
```

Comment: Still confused. I maintain the connecting sockets in `app.js`, which doesn't seem to be work inside routes.